# Injecting Services into a Base Controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, controller, initialization

### Scenario:

An MVC3 app that uses constructor injection to provide services for a given controller:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IArticleService _articleService;

    public HomeController(IArticleService articleService)
    {
        _articleService = articleService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // do stuff with services
        return View()
    }
}
```

### Intention:

I have a `UserService` that fetches user principal data from Active Directory that I want usable from all my Controllers, from the base controller.

I have tried to inject this service into my `BaseController` like this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public BaseController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
}
```

All by itself it looks fine, but now the constructor in my `HomeController` is off, as it needs a `: base()` initializer. The trouble is, the base initializer is not parameterless due the `UserService` injection.

```
public HomeController(IArticleService articleService) : base(IUserService userService)
```

The code above results in syntax errors.

### Question(s):

How do I properly inject a service into my `BaseController` and initialize it from the child Controller classes (ex. HomeController)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The user service interface must be included in the child controllers' constructor arguments in addition to the base initializer arguments. Like this:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IArticleService _articleService;

    public HomeController(IArticleService articleService, IUserService userService) : base(userService)
    {
        _articleService = articleService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // do stuff with services
        return View()
    }
}
```

**Note:** in order to do anything with the base controller's `UserService` from the inherited controllers, change the access modified from `private` to `protected`.

Comment: Right on. Just poor syntax on my part then. I was thinking if I mentioned `userService` in my `HomeController` constructor arguments that I would have to do something more inside the constructor with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `IUserService` as a `Constructor Parameter` and pass it down to the Base implementation. If the `Ninject Container` config is valid this should suffice:

```
public HomeController(IArticleService articleService, IUserService userService) :
       base(userService)
{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to inject services (and other dependencies) is to use IoC/DI container. ASP.NET MVC has everything in it to make it possible, here is an explanation of [how to make it happen](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/01/21/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-dependencyresolver-and-controlleractivator.aspx).

Anyway, even without any DI you can build your own small IControllerActivator and inject your services there in a way it suits you.